# Gridview textbox multi line only for one single case

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I am new to asp.net and I have a special issue,

I have to load a gridview from some database values...

I have 2 columns in my gridview one a label and one a textbox..

for a special value in the label the textbox should be multiline..for rest other cases the textmode should be single line...

can some one help me how to solve this issue??

PS: let me know if my question is not clear I can explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said ur new, so if in case you didn't know how to convert bound field to template field  , follow this turtorial:

[Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx)

once u convert to template filed then on RowDataBound do like this:

```
void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
{
TextBox myfieldtxt = gRow.FindControl("yourTxtBxID") as TextBox;
Label myLable = gRow.FindControl("yourLableID") as Label;

if(myLable.Text.Equals("XYZ"))
{
  myfieldtxt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
}
else
{
 myfieldtxt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Single;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [GridView.RowDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)

Then find the value and if its match, you can change the property `TextMode`

```
protected void GVRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            var txb= (TextBox) e.Row.FindControl("TextBoxID"); 

        }
```

Comment: thanks so much for the reply.. can u please help me how to capture the textbox and change the textmode peoperty.. like can u use gridview1.Findcontrol(Textbox1).textmode.. i mean how can i get hold of my textbox properties???

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Text='Sometext'
            TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: My question is textbox should be multiline only in one case when the lable text says "xyz" not for all cases!! can u help??

Comment: Yes you can do by display the data using a TemplateField instead of BoundField.